# word for attribute that is simultaneously positive and negative

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes an attribute Y, where you could say 
`The good thing about X is Y, the problem with X is Y`

note that it's not a neutral attribute, it's simultaneously good *and* bad.

is there such a word in the English language?

preferably I'd like to be able to say something along the lines of:

`Y is a ______ of X; it's good because of blah, but it also causes bleh problems`

Comment: A frequent idiom is to say that "having Y is a mixed benefit".

Comment: @WS2 that's a pretty good idiom! I was really hoping for a single word, but lacking that I guess your idiom will do. I updated my question to clarify this

Comment: Double-edged sword? Is there something that necessitates a single-word? Does this have to fit a slot in some poem?

Comment: Double-edged sword is also pretty good! I'd be using this in a presentation so I am absolutely free to rephrase it, I did have a specific phrasing in mind, but I can't seem to find the missing word for it. I'll leave this up a bit longer in case someone comes along with a even better alternative. and no, it doesn't necessarily have to be a single word, although I would prefer it if there is one

Comment: Along the same lines as *double-edged sword* is ***boon and bane***. My initial thought was from a quote used by the TV character *Monk*, *"It's a blessing and a curse."*, when speaking about his quirky problem solving skills.

Comment: many good answers in the comments! thanks guys! it seems there isn't a single word to convey this meaning, meaning the above idioms is the best the English language can provide. If anyone would bother to create an actual answer to the question I shall accept it! :)